# pandas: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: pandas

I have this code:

```
missing_columns = list(set(model_header) - set(combined_data.columns))
if missing_columns:
    combined_data = combined_data.reindex(columns=np.append(combined_data.columns.values, missing_columns))
```

which is sometimes generating this error

> cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I understand from other posts that this happens when you have a duplicate columns but I don't see how I can given I am adding the missing columns

This is the traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  552.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1590.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
  1287.             response = func(self, request, queryset)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/webcdi/researcher_UI/admin_actions.py" in scoring_data
  20.     return download_data(request, study_obj, administrations)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/webcdi/researcher_UI/views.py" in download_data
  145.         combined_data = combined_data.reindex(columns=np.append(combined_data.columns.values, missing_columns))

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py" in reindex
  2733.                                               **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py" in reindex
  2515.                                   fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py" in _reindex_axes
  2674.                                            fill_value, limit, tolerance)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py" in _reindex_columns
  2699.                                            allow_dups=False)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py" in _reindex_with_indexers
  2627.                                                 copy=copy)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py" in reindex_indexer
  3886.             self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/web-cdi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py" in _can_reindex
  2836.             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

Exception Type: ValueError at /wcadmin/researcher_UI/study/
Exception Value: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I've looked at the columns and I don't see an overlap.  Could this be anything else?

Comment: i think you are trying to assign 2+ same names to 2+ columns. ?

Comment: What is `print (combined_data.columns)` ? Because it seems there are duplicated columns names.

Comment: @jezrael I'm not sure where you're seeing `print (combined_data.columns)` but it is there for me to debug

Comment: @HenryM - no, it is no in your code, be free add it ;)

Comment: @anky_91 I'm finding the difference between one column and another and adding that difference to the one without.  How does that generate duplicates?

Comment: @jezrael it just isn't in the code I put on StackOverflow

Comment: He means you should also add the results of print :)

Comment: So is possible test `print (len(set(combined_data.columns)))` and `print (len((combined_data.columns)))` ?

Comment: 476 to 477 - Thanks.  I know where to look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are duplicated columns names in one or both `DataFrames`, solution is deduplicated them before your solution manually or by code below:

```
model_header = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABDB'))
combined_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCA'))
print (model_header)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, D, B]
Index: []

print (combined_data)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, A]
Index: []
```

---

```
s1 = model_header.columns.to_series()
model_header.columns = (model_header.columns + 
                        s1.groupby(s1).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').str.replace('_0',''))

s2 = combined_data.columns.to_series()
combined_data.columns = (combined_data.columns + 
                         s2.groupby(s2).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').str.replace('_0',''))

print (model_header)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, D, B_1]
Index: []

print (combined_data)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, A_1]
Index: []
```

---

```
missing_columns = list(set(model_header) - set(combined_data.columns))
print (missing_columns)
['D', 'B_1']

if missing_columns:
    combined_data = combined_data.reindex(columns=np.append(combined_data.columns.values, missing_columns))
    print (combined_data)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, A_1, D, B_1]
Index: []
```