# Why is match.columns.get_loc returning a boolean array, not an indice?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to identify the index position of a particular column name in Python. I used this exact same method previously on the same dataframe and it returned the number of the index position of the column name. However, in this case it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the relevant code:

The dataframe:

```
match.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 25979 entries, 0 to 25978
Data columns (total 68 columns):
id_x                25979 non-null int64
country_id          25979 non-null int64
league_id           25979 non-null int64
season              25979 non-null object
stage               25979 non-null int64
date                25979 non-null object
match_api_id        25979 non-null int64
home_team_api_id    25979 non-null int64
away_team_api_id    25979 non-null int64
home_team_goal      25979 non-null int64
away_team_goal      25979 non-null int64
home_player_1       24755 non-null float64
home_player_2       24664 non-null float64
home_player_3       24698 non-null float64
home_player_4       24656 non-null float64
home_player_5       24663 non-null float64
home_player_6       24654 non-null float64
home_player_7       24752 non-null float64
home_player_8       24670 non-null float64
home_player_9       24706 non-null float64
home_player_10      24543 non-null float64
home_player_11      24424 non-null float64
away_player_1       24745 non-null float64
away_player_2       24701 non-null float64
away_player_3       24686 non-null float64
away_player_4       24658 non-null float64
away_player_5       24644 non-null float64
away_player_6       24666 non-null float64
away_player_7       24744 non-null float64
away_player_8       24638 non-null float64
away_player_9       24651 non-null float64
away_player_10      24538 non-null float64
away_player_11      24425 non-null float64
goal                14217 non-null object
shoton              14217 non-null object
shotoff             14217 non-null object
foulcommit          14217 non-null object
card                14217 non-null object
cross               14217 non-null object
corner              14217 non-null object
possession          14217 non-null object
BSA                 14161 non-null float64
Home Team           25979 non-null object
Away Team           25979 non-null object
name_x              25979 non-null object
name_y              25979 non-null object
home_player_1       24755 non-null object
home_player_2       24664 non-null object
home_player_3       24698 non-null object
home_player_4       24656 non-null object
home_player_5       24663 non-null object
home_player_6       24654 non-null object
home_player_7       24752 non-null object
home_player_8       24670 non-null object
home_player_9       24706 non-null object
home_player_10      24543 non-null object
home_player_11      24424 non-null object
away_player_1       24745 non-null object
away_player_2       24701 non-null object
away_player_3       24686 non-null object
away_player_4       24658 non-null object
away_player_5       24644 non-null object
away_player_6       24666 non-null object
away_player_7       24744 non-null object
away_player_8       24638 non-null object
away_player_9       24651 non-null object
away_player_10      24538 non-null object
away_player_11      24425 non-null object
dtypes: float64(23), int64(9), object(36)
```

Rest of code:

```
#remove rows that dont contain player names

column_start = match.columns.get_loc("home_player_1")
column_start
column_end = match.columns.get_loc("away_player_11")
columns = match.columns[column_start:column_end]
#match.dropna(axis=columns)
```

This causes the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is both columns are duplicated, `home_player_1` and also `away_player_11` (and many another columns too).

So if same values in columns you can remove duplicated columns by:

```
match = match.loc[:, ~match.columns.duplicated()]
```

Or you can deduplicate columns names by:

```
s = match.columns.to_series()
match.columns = (match.columns + 
                 s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').str.replace('_0',''))
```

Comment: Ok thanks. In all honesty i don't really understand the second method. I assume match.columns is on the RHS too to stop you mutating the match.columns series. But why can't you mutate it? I guess I'll just look up the individual methods in the rest to understand it all.

Comment: @Sean - second method is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56649670/2901002) - it add counter value for duplicated columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your index column is monotonic, because if not, it will not return the index number but a boolean array.

```
print(df.Index.is_monotonic)
```

At least if you don't want to modify the index column, you can try to add a step like:

```
df.index[matchArray] == True].tolist()
```

Comment: So if the values listed under that column are monotonic, it returns a boolean? And why is that the case anyway? Doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: It's the opposite, if index is not monotonic, it will return a boolean array. You probably lose the monotonic status due to a duplicate entry (specially if you did a set_index)